# PHP detect browser support a tag

Tags: html, cross-browser

For important tags, you may check it manually you check if browser is IE, FF, Opera, lynx! , ... 
but you cannot check all ones. What I am looking for is such a php function(or even client side!):

```
is_supported_tag('<bdi>',$user_agent);
```

`<bdi>` tag is a minor tag and runs on firefox and chrome only but later will be added to the other browsers and I look for rendering page automatically and not checking browser news each week!

putting `<bdi>` tag will not make problem for other browsers but I'm worried about SEO to detect incompatibility.

if browser does not support it, I want it to be removed.

is there such a detection way?

Comment: *"I'm worried about SEO to detect incompatibility"---I can't imagine what SEO would have to do with this.

Comment: @Juhana if seo detect you use tags not supported by Opera browser, your site would be ranked down for people searching from Opera browser.

Comment: Ha ha yeah, that's not going to happen.

Comment: Juhana is right. Also: If it would be like that, all HTML5 pages wouldn't be visible for IE8 and you would have to hide the tags not for the Opera users but for the bots themselves.

Comment: @Juhana do you have any reference?

Comment: SEO is not an issue here. Seriously. You might have layout problems on old browsers if your site depends on it; that is a legitimate concern, but it won't have any effect at all on your SEO.

Comment: It's obvious that search engines don't do compatibility checks. Even *if* that were the case, your plan won't work: as insertusernamehere says, search engines don't use browsers to access the site but bots. If you hide the tags from e.g. Opera, the search engines wouldn't know about that because they'll never use or identify as Opera to index your site.

Comment: iF bad tags actually affected SEO, half the sites on the net probably wouldn't show up

Answer (score 1):

You can't check it using PHP, except you have a list with all supported tags for all different browsers. In this case you can compare the user agent and the tag against that list.

You can use JavaScript on the client side to check for that very easily:

- try to create a new element of the given tag
- check the constructor for `HTMLUnknownElement`

**JavaScript**

```
if (document.createElement('bdi').constructor == HTMLUnknownElement) {
    console.log('This seems not to be supported by this or any other browser');
}
```

You gotta do both things, as the element will always be created, no matter it exists or not. 
`document.createElement('someRandomTagName')` will never fail.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/5GzHq/)

Comment: @arumat Ah sorry, my bad. I was missing the `.constructor` in the hurry. Updated the answer.

Comment: Though the odd thing is that Firefox and Opera both didn't pass this test, even though the MDN says, that [Firefox supports this tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi#Browser_compatibility); on the other hand Safari passes.